# OpenID4Java to OpenID Connect

Tags: openid, google-openid, openid-connect, openid4java

We are using OpenID4Java library in code. How can we upgrade to OpenID Connect as recommended but Google:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

Comment: You might find the following blog useful when migration your Google OpenID2 implementation to OpenID Connect: https://arvados.org/blogs/30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenID4Java library only supports OpenID 2.0 and 1.0. For OpenID Connect you'll need to consider a different library. You can pick one from the (Java) options listed on the following page: http://openid.net/developers/libraries/

Comment: Hans, Any suggestions on which library to use?